# XCode Instruments not detecting Zombie with BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, instruments, xcode4.2

Usually, when I try to fix a BAD_ACCESS error I open the Xcode Instruments and test to find the zombies that are causing the error.

I'm running my app with iPhone 5.0 simulator. It stops with BAD_ACCESS, but Instruments doesn't flags any zombie.

The behavior is totally different when I run the app with iPhone 4.3 simulator. In this case, the application runs very well without any BAD_ACCESS.

I'm using XCode 4.2.

What could be happening?

Here's the backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0167209b in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x00002ff2 in -[BSViewController viewDidAppear:] (self=0x1, _cmd=0x12ddd81, animated=1 '\001') at BSViewController.m:42
#2  0x012616f8 in __CFStringAppendFormatCore ()
#3  0x011acb6c in _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux ()
#4  0x0122bce8 in _CFLogvEx ()
#5  0x00b26b63 in NSLogv ()
#6  0x00b26ad5 in NSLog ()
#7  0x00009ffc in -[BSCTView buildFrames] (self=0x6a55f80, _cmd=0xd541) at BSCTView.m:96
#8  0x0000a5da in -[BSCTView layoutSubviews] (self=0x6a55f80, _cmd=0x66a6c4) at BSCTView.m:124
#9  0x001ff301 in -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] ()
#10 0x01284e72 in -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] ()
#11 0x0283592d in -[CALayer layoutSublayers] ()
#12 0x0283f827 in CA::Layer::layout_if_needed ()
#13 0x027c5fa7 in CA::Context::commit_transaction ()
#14 0x027c7ea6 in CA::Transaction::commit ()
#15 0x0285330c in +[CATransaction flush] ()
#16 0x001bf4c6 in -[UIApplication _reportAppLaunchFinished] ()
#17 0x001bfbd6 in -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] ()
#18 0x001ce743 in -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] ()
#19 0x001cf1f8 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#20 0x001c2aa9 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#21 0x01748fa9 in PurpleEventCallback ()
#22 0x012571c5 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#23 0x011bc022 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#24 0x011ba90a in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#25 0x011b9db4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#26 0x011b9ccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#27 0x001bf2a7 in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#28 0x001c0a9b in UIApplicationMain ()
#29 0x000027a0 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff578) at main.m:16
```

Comment: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` can be caused by zillions of different possible errors, only one of which is zombie objects.  Without any code, it's impossible to say.  What is the stack trace when the error occurs?

Comment: Yes, I know that without the code is difficult to say, but the code is very large to copy here and the BAD_ACCESS happens on places that doesn't say much. I'm editing the question adding the backtrace.

Comment: wow, `self=0x1` is a very broken state (re: line #1).

Comment: I'm fighting this error since this morning and finally figured out... A call to NSLog was receiving a parameter that were an int and on the format I was using "Foo %@" instead of "Foo %d". I don't know why this wouldn't fire a BAD_ACCESS on 4.3 simulator.

Comment: Just when @AdamRosenfield asked me the backtrace I read it with more attention and saw that NSLog on line #6. Thanks Adam!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said above by @AdamRosenfield, on question comments, `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` can be caused by many other things that aren't zombies.

In this specific case, the problem was an `NSLog()` with a format string that expected an object `@"%@"` and was receiving an `int` as a parameter, as the example bellow.

```
int variable = 1;
NSLog(@"%@", variable);
```

This was causing the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

After reading the backtrace, I saw that line `#6` and searched all `NSLog()` calls on code to finally found the one with error.